# Are there any way to different the long press on PowerButton and the press on HomeButton in Android Normal Application?

Tags: android

I know when pressed the HomeButton ,I can receive a broadcast name `Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS`,but my application want to have different function on the HomeButton and the LongPress PowerButton, and the two actions is sending the same broadcast when the action happened.

Now how can i differnet the two action for my normal application?